# Make a subsection appear in the toc without a subsection existing

Tags: table-of-contents, subsection

I have a section and within it several tables. Each one on a page. I intend that in the toc, the name of each one of these tables appears as if it were a subsection.
I have tried the following command just above the code of the table:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Text 1}
```

it appears in the toc, but the page number is not the one that corresponds to it.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Tables are floats and can end on some other page. If you put the command `\addcontentsline` next to the caption, the page number will be correct.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\listoftables
\clearpage

\section {Some Tables}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{Table I}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{T-\thetable~Table I}% <<<<<<<<<<<<
\end{table}

\newpage
\begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{Table II}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{T-\thetable~Table II}% <<<<<<<<<<<<
\end{table}
    
\newpage
\begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{Table III}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{T-\thetable~Table III}% <<<<<<<<<<<<
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```